# My transform of dataframe results in type error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

This code is throwing a type error, yet I cannot seem to pinpoint exactly what the issue is.
I'm assuming my frame has some bad data, however there are 10,000 rows, so tough to understand whats happening there.

for i in cat_cols:
    data_frame[i] = lbl.fit_transform(data_frame[i].fillna('0'))

Error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test_makeprediction.py",
> line 187, in test_maximum_condition
>     test_response = MakePrediction.predict(json_input)   File "C:\dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\predict-1.0.0-py3.7.egg\prediction\makeprediction.py",
> line 51, in predict
>     data_frame[i] = lbl.fit_transform(data_frame[i].fillna('0'))   File
> "C:\dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py",
> line 236, in fit_transform
>     self.classes_, y = _encode(y, encode=True)   File "C:\dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py",
> line 107, in _encode
>     raise TypeError("argument must be a string or number") TypeError: argument must be a string or number
```

---

I added some additional code, but it generates a new error.

## Transform to Numerical Values for Comparison

```
for i in cat_cols.describe(include=[np.object, np.numeric]).columns:
```

I'm very confident this has something to do with the way the JSON is coming from my API, however everything I can see looks like it checks out.

```
New Error:
Data Frame Row Count: 10000
Category Count: 74
Numerical Count: 19
[2019-10-02 13:45:31,993] ERROR in app: Exception on /predict [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "predictservice.py", line 63, in predict
    return_response = MakePrediction.predict(json_obj)
  File "C:\dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\predict-1.0.0-py3.7.egg\prediction\makeprediction.py", line 50, in predict
    for i in cat_cols.describe(include=[np.object, np.numeric]).columns:
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'describe'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Keep in mind that code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant (never executed), and it should not be included here (just creates unnecessary clutter - edited & removed).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
for i in data_frame.describe(include=[object, bool]).columns:

    data_frame[i] = lbl.fit_transform(
        data_frame[i].fillna('0')
    )
```

with `.describe(include=[object, bool])` I make sure I only take categoric or Boolean columns.

Other alternative:

```
for i in cat_cols:

    data_frame[i] = lbl.fit_transform(
        data_frame[i].fillna('0').astype(str)
    )
```

Comment: It looks like I cannot use describe because CAT_COLS is an index dataframe.

Comment: try: data_frame[i].fillna('0').astype(str)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my issue was resolved by this bit of code, which i found in another stack post.

```
        data_frame[i] = lbl.fit_transform(
            data_frame[i].astype(str).fillna('0')
        )
```